# mongodb & /data/db directory permissions

Tags: linux, mongodb, file-permissions, chmod

I'm trying to run mongod with its defaults so it's using the `/data/db` directory. I changed the owner of the data directory

```
sudo chown mongodb:mongodb /data -R
```

Like so many others i got the following error when first running `mongod`.:

```
2017-04-11T12:32:25.932-0500 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 28596 Unable to determine status of lock file in the data directory /data/db: boost::filesystem::status: Permission denied: "/data/db/mongod.lock", terminating
```

Which makes sense but what doesn't make sense is the only way i can actually run it `mongod` is if i:

```
chmod 777 /data -R
```

If i

```
   chmod 666 /data -R
```

i get the same error. Since this is supposed to be the data directory why does it require execute permission.

i added my user to the mongodb group

```
sudo usermod -g mongodb myuser
```

and then i tried

```
chmod 770 /data -R
```

and its still failing even through i'm a member of the `mongodb` group.

Why am i messing with all this? Because i want to secure the data directory appropriately and don't want to have to run with 777 security.

So the questions are:

1. Why is execute permission required
2. Why am i unable to run it when i was a member of the mongodb group?

Comment: What OS? What is the command you are using to start mongod?

Comment: This `sudo chown mongodb:mongodb /data -R` worked ?? Why is `-R` flag passed after the path?

Comment: @helmy ubuntu 14.04

Comment: @franklinsijo no reason but it seemed to have worked.

Answer (score 2):

Directories need to have execute permission, but the files within the directories do not need execute permission.  Also, as noted by @franklinsijo, -R should be the first parameter to chmod.

To fix things I would do the following:

```
$ sudo chmod -R 770 /data
$ sudo find /data -type f -exec chmod 660 {} \;
```

This will first give everything under /data execute permission, and then return all the normal files to having only read and write, but not execute.

Comment: i get the following error on the find command 'find: paths must precede expression: chmod'